# Cordova/Phonegap push notifications - custom template accessing payload

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I am building an Ionic app with VS2015 (cordova/phonegap), and using the push notification plugin. There is no problem in the actual functionality of the push notifications, I get them correctly and they are displayed to our customers.

What I am trying to do is to get the title and/or id from the payload of the notification.
The registration code is as follows:

```
var template = '{ "data" : {"message":"$(message)", "id": "$(id)", "title": "$(title)"}}';
// Register for 
mobileServiceClient.push.gcm.registerTemplate(e.regid,"CT2", template, NOTIFICATION_TAGS_ARRAY)
```

When I try to access the notification (in function onGCMNotification(e)) I can only see the message and all other params in the payload are undefined (if I try accessing e.payload.id)

Can anyone help me?

Note: I am using the phonegap push plugin - not the Ionic one.

**UPDATE:**
I finally got it to work ***once***, but just for the first notification - so we still have the problem.

What happened was as following:

1. I uninstalled the app and re-installed it.
2. Re-registered my custom template.

Results are that I get the notification twice:

- First time - payload contains only message (not other attributes)
- Second time - I get the complete payload with extra attributes.
- Next time we send a notification and any other time - we get only the message in the payload without the rest of the attributes.

Cordova version 5.1.1

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I am having the same issue.